# How to include third party javascript library in stenciljs?

Tags: stenciljs

I need to inlude this script   `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`
in my stencil component. I included this in the index.html which is in src folder. This is working exactly how i need in the development mode but once i run npm build . This doesn't work. Can someone tell me where do i include this third party library?

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/98) is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try to import it on your component file. this works for me

`import "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js";`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the root of your project, theres a stencil.config.ts file. In there you can specify copy tasks. You can read here how to do this: https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#copy

After you set that up correctly and your ../assets/ folder is being copied to your build folder.

You need to copy your all the external js file inside assets folder.

In your render method you can directly refer js file from /assets/